# word for emotion that's not quite to envy or jealousy

Tags: single-word-requests

*Jealous* is defined as "very watchful or careful in guarding or keeping," and *resentfully envious*. *Envy* is defined as "a feeling of discontent and ill will because of another's advantages, possessions, etc.; resentful dislike of another who has something that one desires." *Jealousy* has stronger emotions attached than *envy*.

Is there a word for feeling sad and missing something you want to be a part of?  For example,

> I'm not feeling jealous, I'm sad and feel like I'm missing for something. I feel _____.

Comment: It might actually be "being envious" — *envious* doesn't usually mean a feeling quite as strong as your definition (although it's right for *envy;* it gets watered down when made into an adjective). Where did your definition come from? Have you looked in more than one dictionary? Have you looked up the **adjectives** *jealous* and *envious* as well?

Comment: I have always rationalized the difference in meaning between jealous and envious in the following way: I am not jealous of your new Ferrari but I am envious. In the former I crave your new car and don't want you to have it, but in the latter, I still crave such a vehicle but I don't want yours or for you to be parted from it.

Comment: Haters is a synonym for envious.

Answer (score 2):

**Longing**

noun

1. a yearning desire.
   "Miranda felt a wistful longing for the old days"

synonyms:   yearning, pining, craving, ache, burning, hunger, thirst, hankering

[GOOG]